# How to create Child Plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Actually I have changed some code in WordPress Store Locator. I want it to remain when plugin will update. So I want to create a child plugin for that. Any ideas on how I could manage it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This varies plugin to plugin, and it sometimes isn't even possible, other times plugins have documentation to extend them easily (such as WooCommerce and Gravity Forms). Some of them create [Action Hooks with `do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) that let you extend the functionality easily. A common example is updating a post after a Gravity Form is submitted with their [`gform_after_submission`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/) hook.

Effectively, it depends on what you want to do, and how the plugin implements the functionality you want to change. If they add text with a [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) or [Anonymous Function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), it will be harder to modify said text, and you may have to look at something strange like doing a run-time find and replace using [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), typically on the [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook.

If you want to remove something a plugin does, you can often unhook it with [`remove_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action). This can be a bit tricky depending on how the plugin is instantiated, sometimes its as simple as:

```
remove_action( 'some_hook', 'function_to_remove' );
```

Other times it's more complicated like:

```
global $plugin_class_var;
remove_action( 'some_hook', array($plugin_class_var, 'function_to_remove') );
```

Those are the basics of extending (or even 'shrinking'?) a plugin's functionality, and it's not *always* doable appropriately. Unfortunately the narrow answer to your question is outside of the scope of what we can provide from StackOverflow.

From here, you'll need to figure out **exactly** what you want to do with the plugin, and dig through the plugin's files to see if there's an appropriate hook or function you can use. If you're still stuck, you'll need to post a new question (don't update this one) with your **exact** desired result and anything you've tried, and the relevant code that goes along with it. "I want to change a plugin without editing core files" isn't nearly specific enough. "I want to replace an icon with a custom icon in this plugin, here's what I've tried" is specific enough to possibly answer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I just went through myself and I had so many changes that I couldn't just override the actions.

I created this tool that allows you to create a child plugin like a child theme. You can make updates to the plugin and still update it without losing your changes.

I'm posting this here because it relates and hopefully becomes useful to the next person who runs into this issue.

https://github.com/ThomasDepole/wordpress-child-plugin-tool

Comment: If this works without any complications, Genius! Question is why is it not allowed as a default function? Because of the large number of plugin mess that it could do to the WordPress ecosystem?

Answer (score 3):

As per WordPress standard, it's called plugin's addon.

if the plugin has provided any action to update that functionality then you can use it with your addon (child plugin).

Here I am sending a link for reference.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Thanks! @Jagir bahesh can you give me any example for WordPress Store Locator plugin.