# how to Build a plugin child?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need to create a child plugin for a popular plugin
There are a few functions in the main plugin that I need to edit (by the Child plugin) How do I do this?
Note: There is a function in the main plugin, I just need to add code to it with the plugin child
Desired function:

```
function dokan_get_social_profile_fields() {
    $fields = array(
        'fb' => array(
            'icon'  => 'facebook-square',
            'title' => __( 'Facebook', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'gplus' => array(
            'icon'  => 'google',
            'title' => __( 'Google', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'twitter' => array(
            'icon'  => 'twitter-square',
            'title' => __( 'Twitter', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'pinterest' => array(
            'icon'  => 'pinterest-square',
            'title' => __( 'Pinterest', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'linkedin' => array(
            'icon'  => 'linkedin-square',
            'title' => __( 'LinkedIn', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'youtube' => array(
            'icon'  => 'youtube-square',
            'title' => __( 'Youtube', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'instagram' => array(
            'icon'  => 'instagram',
            'title' => __( 'Instagram', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'flickr' => array(
            'icon'  => 'flickr',
            'title' => __( 'Flickr', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
    
    );

    return apply_filters( 'dokan_profile_social_fields', $fields );
}
```

The amount I need to add to it with the Child Plugin:

```
,
        'telgram' => array(
            'icon'  => 'telgram',
            'title' => __( 'Telgram', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
        'discord' => array(
            'icon'  => 'discord',
            'title' => __( 'Discord', 'dokan-lite' ),
        ),
```

Comment: please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766761/how-to-create-child-plugin-for-wordpress